# Does winbase::LoadLibrary() load .pdbs?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2010, dll, pdb-files

I have issues with debugging of a library loaded at runtime, and an unknown is:

Does winbase::LoadLibrary() load the .pdb in debugging mode?

Because if it doesn't, that would explain why I cannot use any debugging in my DLL, and if it does, that would at least tell me to search for the problem somewhere else.

Obvious follow-up: If it does not, how do I get VS2010 to load the pdb anyway?

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol file search is conducted whenever a DLL is loaded into your process space, independent of how that happens.  Your problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[The Visual Studio debugger uses the path to the PDB in the EXE or DLL file to find the project.PDB file.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1.aspx)